# Returning "null" from endpoint by PHP

Tags: php, curl, browser, postman

Friends, I have the problem of returning the endpoint https://api.bcb.gov.br/dados/serie/bcdata.sgs.4390/dados for the return by PHP.

In POSTMAN it works normal and the browser also normal.

Where is the problem?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.bcb.gov.br/dados/serie/bcdata.sgs.4390/dados",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic YXRoZW5hc3g6QHRoZW5hc1g=",
    "Cookie: cookie_p=!scLarubhqjnExZBkmDwhOLi4iPSDyREMccf7/KajFSUEMTzB5Ayusi5+tGpJHXS2/gAiOR1B3EXRVmA=; TS01799025=0198c2d644c9f142b44ab6191be6416ca09c966281b4eac2e338095e981a329beb85787a3328474ab13c2f09d86baa6627e734caa34ceb49d8e51f2f880c249de254c0daa1"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From postman and browser it is working because you are loading code and file over https secured connection. If you are doing this on http or localhost you must add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` and `CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'` to emulate browser and get results back.
But using `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` is not really smart and leave you insecure, more about that option and other curl options you can read here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSSLVERIFYPEER

Here is code i tested on localhost that works

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.bcb.gov.br/dados/serie/bcdata.sgs.4390/dados",
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
   CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Basic YXRoZW5hc3g6QHRoZW5hc1g=",
      "Cookie: cookie_p=!scLarubhqjnExZBkmDwhOLi4iPSDyREMccf7/KajFSUEMTzB5Ayusi5+tGpJHXS2/gAiOR1B3EXRVmA=; TS01799025=0198c2d644c9f142b44ab6191be6416ca09c966281b4eac2e338095e981a329beb85787a3328474ab13c2f09d86baa6627e734caa34ceb49d8e51f2f880c249de254c0daa1"
   ),
   // those 2 lines added
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)',
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// decode response 
$obj = json_decode($response);
// output result
var_dump($obj);
```